# Filling Nan values with median in a test set

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, missing-data

I am performing data preparation in order to have my data suitable to fit them into machine learning algorithms. Currently, I am dealing/handling missing values. In this block of code shown below, I am not having an error but rather a confusion. In both code blocks I am applying the same thing but for two different datasets: **train_x_e => train set** and **test_x => test set**. In the first code block, I am filling the nan values from the `train_x_e` which is completely fine. However, in the `test_x` I am not sure if I should be filling the nan values using `train_x_e` or `test_x` as shown in the 2nd code.
If someone could explain this to me I would appreciate it!

## Checking for values of keys whether they are > 0 so we can store the in nan_columns

## Train set

```
 nan_columns = []
    for keys, values in null_vals.items():
        if values > 0:
            nan_columns.append(keys)
    train_x_b = train_x_e.fillna(train_x_e.median())
    print(nan_columns)
```

Same Procedure for test set

## Test set

```
  nan_columns = []
    for keys, values in null_vals.items():
        if values > 0:
            nan_columns.append(keys)
    test_x_b = test_x.fillna(test_x.median())
    print(nan_columns)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @Descartes There is just a confusion that I am having, whats the difference between using the train set to fill the missing values of the test set, and  using test set data to fill the values of the test set itself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're doing it is correct. You should always separate training and testing data. You're testing your model on incoming data, so only information derived from it can be used.

Using median of training data while testing is not as bad as using testing data in training, but notice, that the procedure of preparing data is different for those two datasets. In the first one, median of the same dataset is used, in the second - value not related to the testing dataset.

Also when using training set median, you would have to save it somewhere, together with the model. What if you have 1000 features? You would have to save 1000 values. What if you want an iterative model, do you update those values as well?

The phenomenon of getting one dataset dirty with information from other is called [data leakage](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am kinda new to ML, I didn't understand very well the 3rd part where you are saying to save it somewhere. Do you mean in the way that I am assigning it into a new train/test_x_b, is that the correct way of saving or you are talking about something else. Thanks again!@Andronicus

Comment: @Unix it means when you have your model in production and new data comes, you need to take those medians from somewhere, so you have to calculate them beforehand on training dataset. Also if you update your model with the new data, you also have to update medians.

Comment: @Unix no problem, have a great day and Merry Christmas;)